Apache Camel - toD() timeout: only socketTimeout works, responseTimeout does not
I need to add timeout to toD() as the url comes from header(dynamic). Obviously it's the timeout between establishing the connection until the other end returns anything, so I think responseTimeout is the one. But I found it is not accepted parameter; only socketTimeout is fine.
.toD("${exchangeProperty.url}?socketTimeout=10000", 10) // this is fine
// .toD("${exchangeProperty.url}?responseTimeout=10000", 10) // error of unaccepted parameter

Even the meaning is different, but the goal is somehow achieved and it's OK for me, but I don't know where it is stated. Do we have documentation for that?
It's an HTTP request at last, so I guess HttpComponent is used? The class HttpComponent only contains constants of connectTimeout and socketTimeout, is that why responseTimeout is not accepted?
    @Metadata(
        label = "timeout",
        defaultValue = "-1",
        description = "The timeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection from the connection manager. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default)."
    )
    protected int connectionRequestTimeout = -1;
    @Metadata(
        label = "timeout",
        defaultValue = "-1",
        description = "Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default)."
    )
    protected int connectTimeout = -1;
    @Metadata(
        label = "timeout",
        defaultValue = "-1",
        description = "Defines the socket timeout in milliseconds, which is the timeout for waiting for data  or, put differently, a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets). A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default)."
    )
    protected int socketTimeout = -1;

Apache Camel 3.20.1
